# Threading in python and Queue leads to memory leak or memory error

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-leaks, queue

I had created simple code using multithreading in python with Queue. I have a main thread which keep on adding the Data in the Queue(Queue maxsize is 2000) and there will be 5 different threads who will take out from the Queue and publish into redis at some specific channel.

The code is working perfectly fine , but after 5 or 6 hours , the publish mechanism becomes slow.
As the threads which is used to remove the data from Queue becomes slow, and started throwing the buffer over flow error, as the Queue size reaches to maxsize. the speed of adding the data to queue  is same which was in beginning.

The issue occurs differently on different configuration Linux system. How to identify what kind of error it is throwing? How to debug the problem.

As Stated - the code is very simple , where main thread is required to add the data in the Queue one by one and the 5 other threads can take the data out of the Queue one by one.

## Sharing The Code

```
   import redis
   import logging
   import sys
   logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG)
   redisPub = redis.StrictRedis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379)

def main():
    try:
        recv_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
        recv_sock.bind(("", 8000))
        recv_sock.setblocking(0)
        recv_sock.settimeout(5)
    except Exception,e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        logging.error("Socket Connection Unsuccessful")
        print "Program halted."
        sys.exit()

    sendThEvent     = threading.Event()
    sendThEvent.clear()
    sendPktQ = Queue.Queue(maxsize=2000)
    for i in range(0,5):
        thSend = threading.Thread(name = 'sendThread', target = sendThread , args = (sendPktQ,sendThEvent))
        thSend.setDaemon(True)
        thSend.start()

    packetsCounting = 0
    while True:
        try:
            recvData, recvAddr = recv_sock.recvfrom(2048)
            sendPktQ.put(recvData)
            packetsCounting += 1

            else:
                logging.error("There is some error")
        except socket.timeout:
            continue
        except Exception,e:
            exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
            logging.error(e)



def sendThread(sendPktQ,listenEvent):
    if sendPktQ == None:
        pass
    else:
        while True:
            instanceSentCnt += 1
            if sendPktQ.qsize() < 1:
                event_is_set = listenEvent.wait(0)

            packetDict = sendPktQ.get()
            data = redisPub.publish('chnlName', packetToSend)
            logging.info("packet size reached to ============================================ %s ------------ %s"%(len(packetToSend),data))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Anyone Inputs will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some [minimal code that shows the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: hi Gphilo, i shared the code snippet. kindly give any insights.

Answer (score 0):

I see a `sendPktQ.get()`, but no `sendPktQ.task_done()`, for example:

```py
async def _dispatch_packet(self, destination=None) -> None:
    """Send a command unless in listen_only mode."""
    if not self.command_queue.empty():
        cmd = self.command_queue.get()

        if not (destination is None or self.config.get("listen_only")):
            destination.write(bytearray(f"{cmd}\r\n".encode("ascii")))
            await asyncio.sleep(0.05)

        self.command_queue.task_done()
```

See [queue library docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/queue.html#queue-objects)